# Need visa for 12 hours layover at Seoul airport?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, layovers, south-korea, myanmar-citizens

We are Myanmar passport holders, me and our family are planning to visit Japan and Korea this April. We're planning to book a connecting flight from Japan to Korea, and then to Yangon.

Is it OK for our baggage check through from Tokyo (by Korea Airline) to Seoul (by Vietnam Airline) to Yangon?  Is it also ok for stay 12 hours layover in Seoul Incheon airport?

I booked tickets separately, Myanmar to Seoul (round trip ticket by Vietnam airlines) and Seoul to Tokyo (round trip ticket by Korea airlines)

Answer (score 2):

Citizens of Myanmar require a visa to enter Korea and are not eligible for any of Korea's other exemptions such as the transit tourist program.

You can remain airside without a visa, but your proposed itinerary would require crossing immigration to enter Korea and collect your baggage and transfer it to your next flight yourself.

You will need to obtain a visa for Korea, or book a different itinerary.